# Getting a tagged result with a regular expression

Tags: regex

What would be a basic regular expression which finds `some string` if given the string `quuz="bleh" foo="some string" bar="some other string"` where `some string` and `some other string` are arbitrary strings.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for `some string` or are you looking for any string in between quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any string between quotes:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

Any string between quotes called `foo`:

```
foo="([^"]*)"
```

Any string between quotes, handling escaped quotes correctly, i. e. matching `2\" by 4\"` in `"2\" by 4\""`:

```
"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"
```

In all cases, the overall match includes the surrounding quotes; the capturing group `$1` will contain the string you're interested in. How to access that depends on your regex implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo="([^"]*)"
```

The first (and only) capture group will contain what was between the quotes. It assumes that the contents of the quotes might be empty, but definitely include no double-quote characters.